# Resetting a react-hook-form field value when an inherited value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a variable (selectedDay) which is a value (selectedDate.toString()) passed from a parent component

I set it as the value of a react-hook-form field

it re-renders on screen every time the value from the parent component changes but does not change when I submit the form.

are there any onChange listeners I should add? if so, how do I make sure the form value changes when the inherited value does?

```
const DaySheet = ({ selectedDate }) => {
  const selectedDay = selectedDate.toDateString();

  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, reset } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    try {
      const response = api.post('/sheets/save/', data);
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="form2" key={1}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="txtBox"
        value={selectedDay}
        readOnly={true}
        {...register('date')}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default DaySheet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `reset` method inside a `useEffect` to reset the date value if `selectedDate` is changed. Also add `selectedDate` as a dependency of the `useEffect`.

Could you please try this?

```
const DaySheet = ({ selectedDate }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    reset({ date: selectedDate.toDateString() });
  }, [selectedDate]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="form2" key={1}>
      <input type="text" className="txtBox" {...register('date')} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default DaySheet;
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I'm assuming adding it as a dependency is what triggers the useEffect when the value changes. Either way I guess I have to read up on hooks more.

Comment: Yes, learning about `useEffect` is very useful